# How to Separate Image Collections in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, time-series

In the below code, ERA-5 snow data is called and plotted. Based on this, some of the images detected snow cover and some of them no. So I'm going to know that how can I separate snowy and non-snowy images?

[image]

code link : https://code.earthengine.google.com/42e13a826aff7d53633d8a6952e437b5

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);



var starting = '2019';
var ending = '2020';


var snowCover = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('snow_cover').clip(table);
  return bands.rename('snow')
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};



var era5SnowCover = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY")
.filterDate(starting , ending)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(snowCover);


print(era5SnowCover)
  
print(
  ui.Chart.image.series(era5SnowCover, table, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10000, 'system:time_start')
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Snow Cover Series (ERA-5 Monthly)' + ' ' + starting,
    vAxis: {title: '%'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    series: {0: {color: 'gray'}}
  })
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is first add a property to each image with the mean snow cover, then apply a simple filter of the metadata to get the images you want.

```
  // Add tag to separate null and positive snow images function
var era5SnowCoverTagged = era5SnowCover.map(function(image){
  var era5SnowCoverMean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: table,
    scale: 10000,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).getNumber('snow');
  return image.set('snowCoverMean', era5SnowCoverMean);
});
print(era5SnowCoverTagged);

var era5SnowCoverPos = era5SnowCoverTagged.filterMetadata('snowCoverMean', 'greater_than', 0);
var era5SnowCoverNull = era5SnowCoverTagged.filterMetadata('snowCoverMean', 'equals', 0);
print(era5SnowCoverPos);
print(era5SnowCoverNull);
```

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/34580197614adafe600bec4c62723feb